# basic react-table component not rendering data

Tags: reactjs

This basic react-table code renders the column headers but not the data.

Obviously I'm missing something basic. Could someone explain?

```
    <ReactTable 
        data = {[['one',1],['two',2]]} 
        columns = {[{Header:'One'},{Header:'Two'}]}
    />
```

Comment: Can you tell what library are you using is it materialize.css?

Comment: Just looking at the docs and it seems that columns needs an `accessor` property and data should be an array of objects?

Comment: @RickJolly starting to look that way, although the basic docs say "Simply pass the data prop anything that resembles an array or object". The above data resembles an array in my book. Looks like I'll have to preprocess the row arrays into object. Bah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided invalid `data` and `columns`.
Here is how they should look like

```
const data = [
  {
    someField: 'one',
    anotherField: 1
  },
  {
    someField: 'two',
    anotherField: 2
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Some Field',
    accessor: 'someField'
  },
  {
    Header: 'AnotherField'
    anotherField: 'anotherField'
  }
];
```

And then you render the table like this

```
<ReactTable 
  data = {data} 
  columns = {columns}
/>
```

Comment: Yes it seems the data must be in object not array format. Not well documented